# How to manage several entities with JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring, set, spring-data

**Context**

I'm trying to create a simple API to learn Spring Boot and JPA. Informations are stored into H2 database.

I have 2 entities : `mission` and `user`.

Several users are assigned to a mission. And users can be assigned to different missions.

So, my class `Mission` has an attribute `private ArrayList<User> users;`.

**Objective**

My goal is to create some requests as :

- (GET request) `IP/missions/123456/users` : Get all users assigned to mission `123456`
- (PUT request) `IP/missions/456789` : Assigned users to mission `456789`

So, tied both entities.

**Problematic**

But I don't know how to store/tie informations relative to `mission` and `user`. The good way is to create an "associative table" with the scheme `Assignements(id_user, id_mission)` ?

Thanks for help!

**Edit 1 : Code**

*Entity Mission*

```
@Entity
public class Mission{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date start;
    private Date end;
    private ArrayList<User> users;
    private int status;

    public Mission() {
    }

    public Mission(String name, Date start, Date end) {
        this.name = name;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.status = 0;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

*Entity User*

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

*SQL*

I use a SQL script. Currently, script looks like :

```
INSERT INTO mission (id, name, start, end, status) VALUES ('de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82', 'mission 1', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-13', 0)
INSERT INTO mission (id, name, start, end, status) VALUES ('425e7701-02c6-4de3-9333-a2459eece1c8', 'mission 2', '2019-02-10', '2019-02-15', 0)
```

**Edit 2 : New code (with @ManyToMany)**

*Entities*

```
@Entity
public class Mission {

    @Id
    private String missionid;
    private String namemission;
    private Date start;
    private Date end;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "mission_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "missionid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    )
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    private int status;

    public Mission() {}

    public Mission(String name, Date start, Date end) {
        this.namemission = name;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.status = 0;
    }
}

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private String iduser;
    private String nomuser;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Mission> missions = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {}

    public User(String nom) {
        this.nomuser = nom;
    }

}
```

*Repositories*

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "mission")
public interface MissionResource extends JpaRepository<Mission, String> {
    ...
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user")
public interface UserResource extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
    ...
}
```

*Rest Controller*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/missions", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ExposesResourceFor(Mission.class)
public class MissionRepresentation {
    private final MissionResource missionResource;
    private final UserResource userResource;

    public MissionRepresentation(MissionResource missionResource, UserResource userResource) {
        this.missionResource = missionResource;
        this.userResource = userResource;
    }

    // mapping
}
```

Comment: What is the difficulty with the associative table?

Comment: It's not a difficulty but I don't know if use an associative table is the best way to solve the problem with these tools.

Comment: well it looks to me like a many-to-many association so that seems like the right approach (for rdbms, which since you are using h2 and jpa seems relevant; for nosql the answer would be different).

Comment: Yep I don't use nosql. So you confirm me that the only way with JPA to persist a collection/list is to use associative table? Annotations or another thing don't allow us to do it more simply?

Comment: Show us an attempt. Where is the code?

Comment: @Andronicus I posted the code of my entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to implement a joining table, just as you said. That would be something like:

```
create table mission_user (
    mission_id int,
    user_id int,
    primary key (mission_id, user_id)
)
```

Then a `@ManyToMany` using this table as mapping or entity like `MissionUser` and map both `User` and `Mission` as `@OneToMany` to it.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I have to remove the attribute `ArrayList<User> users`? When the URL `IP/missions/123456/users` is called I get users relative to this mission with a request on `mission_user` table?

Comment: If you use the joining table, then yes, List of `User`s should be replaced with a list of `MissionUser`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why a list of `MissionUser`s is required.

Comment: As i said, you can also use `@JoinTable` instead

Comment: I posted a new edit (Edit 2). Can you tell me if this code is correct according to your answer? Thanks.

Comment: The best would be to run it:) Wasn't it supposed to be `private Set<Mission>` instead of `private Set<Tache>`? Other than that seems ok

Comment: Indeed, stupid mistake :). This code is build wihtout error, so it seems to be good! I have one last question, on my sql script, what I supposed to write if I want fill my database before to do requests with my API? Thanks.

Comment: Yes but the only thing I don't understand is how to write into a list with SQL script ... Or have I to insert into `mission_user` as defined into `Mission` entity. Yep I will do it ;)

Comment: That is not a place for this discussion, please, state another question for that if you have a problem.

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The mission class will have:

```
@Entity
public class Mission {
...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "missions")
    private List<User> users;
...
}
```

and User class will have:

```
@Entity
public class User {
...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Mission> missions;
...
}
```

this will create a table in your database with name something like: missions_uesrs and it will have missionId and userId as only columns.